# Unable to fix broken dependencies on Ubuntu: libssl-dev, libssl1.1, libssl3

Tags: ubuntu

I am facing issues with fixing broken dependencies on my Ubuntu system. When I run the command sudo apt --fix-broken install, I encounter the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20) but 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2 is installed
 libssl1.1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 is installed
 libssl3 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.34) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

I've tried various solutions, including updating, upgrading, and using apt-get, but the issue persists. It seems to be related to the versions of libssl1.1 and libc6.

Comment: Have you tried putting the original 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20 package back? Seems like a good start.

Comment: Have you added packages or repositories manually?

Comment: This is the libssl-dev package that you have installed.  It needs libssl 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.20.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libssl-dev .However, it appears that the version of libssl installed is 1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2. https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/impish/amd64/libssl1.1/1.1.1l-1ubuntu1.2

Comment: While trying to install, i am getting following error
wget: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)